# Failed to compile @noble/curves/abstract/weierstrass on client side

Tags: solana-program, web3.js, solana-wallet-adapter

I am trying to use the latest version of the @solana/web3.js, but I am reaching a compiling error on my client side inside of my create-react-app. I've narrowed down the issue, and I think it may be due to the babel-loader not supporting bigint? I know it's a problem with @solana/web3.js, since the @noble node_module is installed when @solana/web3.js is downloaded. I've searched on the web, and haven't found this specific issue. I've tried deleting my package-lock.json along with the node_nodule folders, and re-installing packages, but that did not work. I'm wondering if anyone has experienced this before, and if there is a way to solve it. The code was working about six months ago in version 1.31.0 of @solana/web3.js, but I recently just came back to my application - upgraded it, broke it, and have not had any success in repairing the issue. Should I use a customized webpack instead of the default provided by Create-React-App? Please let me know what additional information may be required. Errors, versions, and code is below:

Errors:

```
[1] ./node_modules/@noble/curves/abstract/weierstrass.js 1017:57
[1] Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1017:57)
[1] File was processed with these loaders:
[1]  * ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js
[1] You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
[1] |     const u1 = modN(h * is); // u1 = hs^-1 mod n
[1] |     const u2 = modN(r * is); // u2 = rs^-1 mod n
[1] >     const R = Point.BASE.multiplyAndAddUnsafe(P, u1, u2)?.toAffine(); // R = u1⋅G + u2⋅P
[1] |     if (!R) return false;
[1] |     const v = modN(R.x);
```

Package.json Client

```
 {
  "name": "client",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "proxy": "http://localhost:3001",
  "dependencies": {
    "@apollo/client": "^3.8.3",
    "@salte-auth/auth0": "^3.1.0",
    "@salte-auth/salte-auth": "^3.0.10",
    "@solana/web3.js": "^1.78.5",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^6.1.3",
    "axios": "^1.5.0",
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "bigint-buffer": "^1.1.5",
    "bootstrap": "^5.3.2",
    "dotenv": "^16.3.1",
    "graphql": "^16.8.0",
    "jwt-decode": "^3.1.2",
    "moment": "^2.29.4",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-bootstrap": "^2.8.0",
    "react-circular-progressbar": "^2.1.0",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-moment": "^1.1.3",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.3.0",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "web-vitals": "^3.4.0",
    "websocket": "^1.0.34"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "startWebpack": "webpack serve --mode development --open",
    "buildWebpack": "webpack --mode production",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object": "^7.21.11",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-bigint": "^7.8.3"
  }
}
```

Login

```
const solanaWeb3 = require('@solana/web3.js');

const syncPhantom = async () => {

        //Check to see if user has Phantom Wallet Installed
        if ("phantom" in window) {
            console.log("In the window");
            const provider = window.phantom?.solana;
            if (provider.isPhantom) {
                console.log("The provider is found")
                //Connect to Phantom Wallet, and set Public Key
                try {
                    
                    console.log("before connection");
                    const network = "https://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com";
                    const connection = new solanaWeb3.Connection(network);

                    console.log("After connection");
                    const resp = await window.phantom.solana.connect();
                    const keyString = resp.publicKey.toString();
                    console.log("After key string");
                    // const resp = await provider.connect();
                    // console.log(resp);
                    // const keyString = resp.publicKey.toString();


                    await storePubKey({
                        variables: {
                            id: userId,
                            pubKey: keyString
                        }
                    })

                    const phantomAccount = await connection.getAccountInfo(resp.publicKey);

                    await storeWalletValue({
                        variables: {
                            id: userId,
                            walletAmount: parseFloat((phantomAccount.lamports / 1000000000))
                        }
                    })

                    refetch();

                } catch (e) {

                    console.log(e);

                }
            } else {
                console.log("Test fail")
            }
        } else {

            setDirect(true);

        }

    }
```

Comment: The problem is with the `?` - optional chaining - code in that line. You need to configure Babel/tsconfig to either accept optional chaining or transpile it. Do you have a `tsconfig.json` in your project?

Comment: I do not have a tsconfig.json. In lieu of ejecting from the reacts default webpack & babel settings for custom settings, since only @solana/web3.js module was failing compilation, I just included the scripts provided by solana/web3js in my index.html inside my public folder.

''<!-- Development (un-minified) -->
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@solana/web3.js@latest/lib/index.iife.js"></script>''

''<!-- Production (minified) -->
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@solana/web3.js@latest/lib/index.iife.min.js"></script>''

This has been a decent workaround for now.